# How to dynamically display button on GridView according to Cell value

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview

I wonder if anyone can help me with this code. 
What I am trying to do, is to read records from a database and display them on a gridview. However my last column of the grid is a `TemplateField` which I display an `ImageButton` to do something once clicked.

My problem is :

How to display the `ImageButton` only when a particularly Cell of the grid is value `true`. 
I was trying to set the `ImageButton` to false when the value was `false`, but it is not working

Any help please

---

```
private void BindCustomDateBookings()
{
    try
    {

        String queryCustomDateBookings = "Select * from bookings";
        //Creates a connection to the database
        SqlConnection connectionViewBookings = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        //Query builder
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapterViewBookings = new SqlDataAdapter(queryCustomDateBookings, connectionViewBookings);
        dataAdapterViewBookings.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customDate", customDate);

        //Create the data that will hold the result of DB
        DataSet dataSetViewTodaysBookings = new DataSet();

        //open, save results and close connection
        connectionViewBookings.Open();
        dataAdapterViewBookings.Fill(dataSetViewTodaysBookings);
        connectionViewBookings.Close();

        //fill the grid with results
        GridViewCustomDate.DataSource = dataSetViewTodaysBookings.Tables[0];
        GridViewCustomDate.DataBind();
     }
    catch (SqlException SqlExceptionTomorrow)
    {
        Response.Write(@"<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert('Could not connect to the database This date bookings')</SCRIPT>");
    }  
}//Ends Bind Custom Date bookings
```

---

And the grid view has the following coded

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewCustomDate" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="viewBookingTable" GridLines="None"  
             HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridViewHeader">
             <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeader" />
             <RowStyle CssClass="GridViewRowStyle" />
             <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridViewAlternatingRowStyle " />

              <Columns>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="bookingID" ItemStyle-CssClass="displayGridViewID" 
                      HeaderStyle-CssClass="displayGridViewID" >
                  <HeaderStyle CssClass="displayGridViewID" />
                  <ItemStyle CssClass="displayGridViewID" />
                  </asp:BoundField>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="visitorName" HeaderText="Visitor Name" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="contactNo" HeaderText="contactNo" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="hostName" HeaderText="Host Name" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="roomName" HeaderText="Room Name" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="timeIn" HeaderText="Time In" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="smartCardNo" HeaderText="Smart Card No" />
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Required Access">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:ImageButton ID="btnGetRequiredAccessCustomDate" runat="server" 
                              ImageUrl="~/images/buttons/clickMe.png" 
                              onclick="btnGetRequiredAccessCustomDate_Click" />
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>             

        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the Visible property of the asp:ImageButton to a Boolean value in you dataset.  e.g.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnGetRequiredAccessCustomDate" runat="server" 
    Visible=<%# Eval("ShowImage") %>
    ImageUrl="~/images/buttons/clickMe.png" 
    onclick="btnGetRequiredAccessCustomDate_Click" />
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for that I spent a few days trying to do it and with your help it was much better. Thank yuo

Answer (score 1):

Use the `OnDataBound` property in gridview. Your gridview initialisation will be,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewCustomDate" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="viewBookingTable" GridLines="None"  OnDataBound="GridViewCustomDate_DataBound"
             HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridViewHeader">
             <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeader" />
             <RowStyle CssClass="GridViewRowStyle" />
             <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridViewAlternatingRowStyle " />
```

Handle the databound event in the code behind as follows.

```
public void GridViewCustomDate_DataBound(object send, EventArgs e)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < GridViewCustomDate.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         if( condition) // the condition for which you want to check true of false
        GridViewCustomDate.Rows[i].Cells[7].Visible = false; //the cells[7] indicates the last cell. replace with appropriate cell number.
     }
}
```

The **DataBound** method will be called after the databind of the gridview and before it is rendered on the page. So, if the `if` condition fails, then the cell will the **empty**. If the condition is satisfied then the cell with the button will be **shown**.

Basically you render buttons for all the rows and you dynamically hide it after `databind`.

Answer (score 0):

Use data binding and a converter ?

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnGetRequiredAccessCustomDate" runat="server" 
    Visibility={Binding FieldThatControlsVisibility, Converter={StaticResource ConverterForFieldThatReturnsVisibility}}
    ImageUrl="~/images/buttons/clickMe.png" 
    onclick="btnGetRequiredAccessCustomDate_Click" />
```

(Syntax probably not correct because used to working in xaml, but a quick search shows that Visibility property of an ImageButton is a bindable property.